# stratigraphic ranking with field calculator?

Tags: database, arcpy

I would like to populate a feature class float attribute with a numerical ranking of a text attribute of a geologic map. I have a field named [sheet_unit] with strings such as "H10, Q" and "J10, Pl" with I would like to relabel in another attribute [Stratigraphic_Rank] with a numerical value such as 0 and 10, etc. I was hoping to use an IF THEN statement but I cannot for the life of figure out how to use the field calculator to do this. Anyone willing to help me start?

This and my several variations of it don't work:

If [sheet_unit] = "H10, Q" THEN
[Stratigraphic_Rank] = 0
ElseIf [sheet_unit] = "J10, Pl"
[Stratigraphic_Rank] = 10
EndIf

Answer (score 4):

Create a lookup table of ([sheet_unit], [Stratigraphic_rank]) pairs.  Join this to your original table.  Done!  If you want to make it permanent, use a field calculation to copy the joined value of [Stratigraphic_rank] into a new field, then remove the join.